# WCF service as analogue of windows service - is it possible?

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, wcf, windows-services

I need some "service" that constantly runs as an endless Task doing some job.
The obvious solution is a windows service or a console app.
However, the cost of hosting and the cost of renting the whole server differ a lot and that's why the mentioned option (win service) is not good cause I'd have to rent the whole server.

So I was wondering if there is another solution to do this job?
I was thinking of a WCF service that runs as a singleton processing the requests of all the clients. However I have some doubts: I guess after I close my browser where I initiate the work of the WCF service, the serivce itself will stop the work too. Thus, if I want to use this option, I'd have to keep a browser open for as long as I want my service working.

Another option is SQL jobs.However I dont like it because it would be a pain in an ass.

So, looks like the only valid option is win service/console app? If yes, do you know maybe the budget server rental?

Comment: AWS micro instance would be enough for your service? it's quite a small server, but It's free for the first year.

Comment: WCF doesn't run a server inside of a browser, I'm not sure where your starting assumptions are coming from and/or what they actually are.

Comment: @PrestonGuillot OP doesn't say anything about `WCF server running inside of a browser` I'm not sure how you concluded this.

Comment: I believe if you set `InstanceMode` to `Single` you get a persistent instance, for what its worth. Probably not the best design in general though.

Comment: Can't you just start a background thread? Being aware that an IIS worker can exit at any time without warning of course.

Comment: You might want to consider Azure WebJobs: http://www.troyhunt.com/2015/01/azure-webjobs-are-awesome-and-you.html